# MYSQL last_insert_id() and concurrency

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I have a simple MYSQL question. If I make a query that contains **LAST_INSERT_ID()** right after an **INSERT QUERY** running on a web page which has many concurrent users accessing other pages that perform **INSERT** operations would the value of **LAST_INSERT_ID()** be adulterated/corrupted?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it will return the insert id from the current connection. As long as your script hasn't made any other inserts, you will get the one you want.

Also be aware that this will only return a generated ID (e.g. an auto-increment). If you are creating your own ID's it won't return this to you.

Comment: what if from one connection are many parallel threads inserting, will be thread safe? or I need a transaction scope for insert +  LAST_INSERT_ID() ? i cant find information related to that point :/

Comment: Have you any documentation to back this statement up?

Comment: The same connection could be used from multiple threads running in parallel. So currently there can be inserts and LAST_INSERT_ID executed in parallel. It is not clear how that combination of queries will work in a concurrency context.

Comment: last_insert_id would fail if there's another query running before that on the same connection