# How to insert data to two tables on relationship with unknown PK of first table?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

for example if we have to tables:

```
 *table_auther:
 a_id : INT PK
 a_name: varchar(50)

*table_books:
 b_id : INT PK
 b_name: varchar(50)
 a_id : INT FK
```

How to insert data of auther and his one or more books ,if I don't know the auther `a_id` what will be. what's the statement should be?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question.  Are you looking for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?  Insert into `table_author`, get the last inserted id, then insert into `table_books`?

Comment: will not be accurate, if there is multiple users in the same time.

Comment: Are you worried about concurrency issues?  See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185666/mysql-last-insert-id-and-concurrency

Comment: thank u, i think it's useful. what's the insert statement should I use with "LAST_INSERT_ID()"of inserting author and his book - in one step?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dumby record for the author and update it later.

Or, if you have the information about the author available, just insert it first.

Comment: It will be in one step, what's best practice on making "dumby" record and make us sure that record will no repeated?

Comment: Best practice is to have the correct author record in the author table before inserting the book record.